# Get a specific attribute taxonomy terms slug

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy, product

I'm trying to get terms slug from a specific attribute taxonomy but I get nothing.

```
$attr_langs = 'pa_languages';
$attr_langs_meta = get_post_meta('id', 'attribute_'.$attr_langs, true);
$term = get_term_by('slug', $attr_langs_meta, $attr_langs);
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that it doesn't work as [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) first function **argument** needs to be a **numerical value** but **NOT** a **text string** as `'id'` (the post ID)… 
So you can't get any value for `$attr_langs_meta` variable.

> You can get the product ID in different ways:
>
> 1) From the WP_Post object with:
>
> ```
> global $post; 
> $product_id = $post->ID;
> ```
>
> 2) From the WC_Product object with:
>
> ```
> $product_id = $product->get_id();
> ```

Now the correct way for to do it is:

```
// The defined product attribute taxonomy
$taxonomy = 'pa_languages';

// Get an instance of the WC_Product Object (necessary if you don't have it)  
// from a dynamic $product_id (or defined $product_id)
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);

// Iterating through the product attributes
foreach($product->get_attributes( ) as $attribute){
    // Targeting the defined attribute
    if( $attribute->get_name() == $taxonomy){
        // Iterating through term IDs for this attribute (set for this product)
        foreach($attribute->get_options() as $term_id){
            // Get the term slug
            $term_slug = get_term( $term_id, $taxonomy )->slug;

            // Testing an output
            echo 'Term Slug: '. $term_slug .'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Or also exclusively for a variable product (similar thing):

```
// The defined product attribute taxonomy
$taxonomy = 'pa_languages';

// Get an instance of the WC_Product Object (necessary if you don't have it)  
// from a dynamic $product_id (or defined $product_id)
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);

// Iterating through the variable product variations attributes
foreach ( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $attribute => $terms ) {
    // Targeting the defined attribute
    if( $attribute == $taxonomy ){
        // Iterating through term slugs for this attribute (set for this product)
        foreach( $terms as $term_slug ){
            // Testing an output
            echo 'Term Slug: ' . $term_slug . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

This should work for you…

Comment: thank you for the answer but I'd like to mention the product is variable and i can't pre-define it so I had to use `$product_id = $product->get_id();` to make it dynamic however is there a simpler workaround for this script?

Comment: @WiTonNope Here the predefined product ID is just an example… it can be dynamic of course. You can use directly the `WC_Product` object `$product;` if you got it, depending where you are using the code… So may be you could tell where you are using this code, (in a function, in a template), may be completing the code in your question and adding some details…